# The solution always returns x=0

Tags: python, function, exception, scope

On using this code I get the value returned 0 always

```
def fi(arr,mini):
    print(arr)
    if(len(arr)<3):
        x = mini
        return 
    for j in range(1,(math.ceil(len(arr)/2) )):
        l1 = 2*j+1
        if(med(arr[0:l1])<mini):
            mini= med(arr[0:l1])
            print("hello", mini)
    fi(arr[1:],mini)
    return x
```

Comment: `fi([], 0)` returns `None`, not 0.

Comment: Please elaborate your question a bit more to get a quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You define `x` only if `len(arr) < 3`. In other cases it is unassigned. You should add a default value *before* the `if` block, or within an `else` block depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: But due to recursion, it is being referenced only after len(arr) has become less than 3. Hence it is accessed only after being assigned. Please correct me

Comment: No, because you are not `return`ing the result of your recursive call, therefore `return x` always executes.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared `x` before assigning it to `mini`. What should your function return by default?

Answer (score 0):

you define local variable 'x' whose scope is limited to if block and you are trying to return this variable from the function, so it's getting undefined. Better define local variable x in the function and give it some default value which should be return by the function.

```
def fi(arr,mini):
    x = some_default_value
    print(arr)
    if(len(arr)<3):
        x = mini
        return 
    for j in range(1,(math.ceil(len(arr)/2) )):
        l1 = 2*j+1
        if(med(arr[0:l1])<mini):
            mini= med(arr[0:l1])
            print("hello", mini)
    fi(arr[1:],mini)
    return x
```

Comment: Did this. It is  now always printing the default value